# Exact sequence in which $M/\operatorname{Ker}f$ and $\operatorname{Im}f$ appear

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a ring and $M,N$ be $R$-module.
Let $f:M→N$. I'm looking for an exact sequence in which $M,N,\operatorname{Im}f,M/\operatorname{Ker}f$ appear.

Do you have any good ideas?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want this exact sequence? It is fairly easy to construct 3 short exact sequences containing these and then you can put them together to make a new exact sequence which contains all of them (In fact you could be really lazy and just have a short exact sequence for each space and then put those together). But doing this doesn't really tell us anything, so that is why it would help to know why you want this exact sequence, or otherwise to add adittional restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $$0 \longrightarrow M/\text{ker}(f) \longrightarrow N \to \text{coker}(f) \to 0$$ is a short exact sequence, where $\text{coker}(f)=N/\text{im}(f)$.

Note that the map $M/\text{ker}(f) \longrightarrow N$ is monomorphism and the map $N \to \text{coker}(f)$ is epimorphism.